# AI Generated posts (ChatGPT)

Tags: discussion

There is an ongoing discussion on how the SE Network will treat AI-generated contributions. To be more specific, contributions generated by ChatGPT.

Stack Overflow has temporarily banned them from the site because ***"the average rate of getting correct answers from ChatGPT is too low"***, as you can read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). Another related post on the Stack Exchange Meta can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/787042).

We have decided internally to follow the example of SO on this subject. Since we are a relatively small community, the impact on our site should be rather low.

However, if you notice content that doesn't make any sense or gives you a reason to suspect that it might be AI-generated, please feel free to raise a moderator flag and we will look into it. Don't hesitate if you are not sure. If you have plausible arguments, we won't reject the flag, even though your suspicion might turn out to be wrong or not provable.

The Computer Graphics Mod Team